# The missing file is Xamarin.Forms.props?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, upgrade

I am having a similar kind of issue, once I upgraded to 15.5 then..nothing is working ..even a blank template is not going for a build ?

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. The missing file is ....\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.121934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Similar to what? Please clarify

Comment: Have you tried to restore NuGet package? If not, please right click the solution name and choose ‘Restore NuGet Packages’, if it is failed, please share the detail error message in the Output window in here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this today. Try unloading the project in Visual Studio and edit the csproj file. Search for that props file reference in the file. I had two--one from the current version and one outdated version as well. Remove the old one and reload the project.

As always, don't do anything without the safety net of source control to roll back if something goes wrong.